# Modify non-unique line in file with sed/awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to replace a line in a file using bash tools like sed or awk. The part that makes this hard is that the line is not unique, so how can I match it?

I'm sure getting the match by itself could be done other ways, but I only know the following command for replacing lines:

```sh
sed -i "s,^    AGE: .*,    AGE: ${age}," profiles.txt
```

The profiles.txt looks like:

```
ALICE:
    AGE: 
    GRADE: 
BOB:
    GRADE: 
    AGE: 
...
```

How can I find the `AGE:` line for a specific person and update it? The fields for each person can be in any order, and so can the people. The people will always have both fields, they're just blank if unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic `sed` script:

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -u student=$1
declare -u key=$2
declare    val=$3

sed -Ei "/^$student:/,/^\S/{ s/$key:.*/$key: $val/; }" profiles.txt
```

Executed:

```
$: cat profiles.txt
ALICE:
    AGE:
    GRADE:
BOB:
    GRADE:
    AGE:

$: update alice grade 70

$: cat profiles.txt
ALICE:
    AGE:
    GRADE: 70
BOB:
    GRADE:
    AGE:
```

`declare -u` automatically uppercases the string assigned to the variable. This was a pretty simple pattern set, so I was able to just use double-quotes.

---

## addendum

this works fine on the last block:

```
$: update bob age 14
$: cat profiles.txt
ALICE:
    AGE:
    GRADE: 70
BOB:
    GRADE:
    AGE: 14
```

The toggle is still on at the end of the file because nothing turns it off, but that is functionally ok. :)

Comment: `/^$student:/,/^\S/{ ... }` says to only perform the code in the curly block between lines that start with the given srudent's uppercase name in the leftmost column and any other non-whitespace in the leftmost column. It's a block-sensistive application.

Comment: It seems that this solution would not work for the last block in the file, but I didn't test that. In my particular case, there is a "..." at the end of the file and entries are added above it, so your solution works perfectly. Props for having it write back to the file and being a one-liner. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this in `awk` to set the age for `BOB`

```
age=10
awk -v val=${age} '/BOB/ {f=1} f && /AGE/ {$0=$0 FS val;f=0} 1' file
ALICE:
    AGE:
    GRADE:
BOB:
    GRADE:
    AGE:  10
...
```

It will find `BOB` and set `f` to true.  The if `f` is true and `AGE` is found, add age and reset `f`

Comment: Theoretically string `BOB` can be anywhere i.e. part of another name i.e. `BOBBY` or even a value. Moreover `AGE:` might already have a value, not necessarily a blank value.

Comment: @anubhava True, depending of OP input.   Name can be fixed to some like this `/^BOB:$/` of its to match exactly.

Comment: @Jotne: If `BOB` does not have an age, but a subsequent `ALICE` has an AGE field, your program would then set the age of Alice. You need to reset `f`also for every line started with a name which is *not* BOB.

Comment: @user1934428 That would be an assumption that OP could give more information on.  But since there are empty fields that are equal, I do assume that its all equal.  At the same time, why is BOB: not a field settings of ALICE?  Due to the tab in front of fields?  That would also be an assumption.

Comment: I did modify it to use `/^BOB:$/` and it worked. Also, in my case, there won't be students without the AGE field unless the file is corrupted.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk` (assuming you want to change `AGE` for person `BOB`):

```
awk -v age=20 -v name='BOB' '/^[[:alpha:]]+:/ {
   p = ($0 ~ "^" name ":")
}
p && /^[[:blank:]]+AGE:/ {
   sub(/AGE:.*/, "AGE: " age)
} 1' file.yml
```

```
ALICE:
    AGE:
    GRADE:
BOB:
    GRADE:
    AGE: 20
```

Comment: "JOEBOB" would match "BOB".

Comment: Thanks @DennisWilliamson, it is fixed in script.